# Use cyrillic .properties file in eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, internationalization

I'm developing a small project and I'd like to use internationalization for it. The problem is that when I try to use .properties file with cyrillic symbols inside, the text is displayed as rubbish. When I hard-code the strings it's displayed just fine.

Here is my code:

```
ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Labels");
btnQuit = new JButton(labels.getString("quit"));
```

And in my .properties file:

quit = Изход

And I get rubbish. When i try

```
btnQuit = new JButton("Изход);
```

It is displayed correctly. As far as I am aware, UTF-8 is the encoding used for the files.

Any ideas?

Comment: define 'As far as I am aware' :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[AnyEdit](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) is an eclipse-plugin that allows you to easily convert your your properties files from and to unicode notation. (avoiding the use of command-line tools like native2ascii)

If you were using the [`Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class alone (without resource bundle), since Java 1.6 you have the option to [load](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) the file with a custom encoding, using a `Reader` (rather than an `InputStream`)

I'd guess you can also use [`new PropertyResourceBundle(reader)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html), rather than `ResourceBundle.getBundle(..)`, where `reader` is:

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     getClass().getResourceAsStream("messages.properties"), "utf-8")));
```

Answer (score 4):

[Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) are ISO-8859-1 encoded by default. You must use `native2ascii` to convert your UTF-8 properties to a valid ISO-8859-1 properties file containing unicode escape sequences for all non-ISO-8859-1 characters.