# How to implement a font that can display french characters

Tags: java

I am currently working on a project with multiple languages we also have french, the only problem is that it displays weird characters, in stead of normal french,

Can some1 help me with this ( its in java ) 
thanks from beforehand

Comment: this could be a font or encoding issue - you need to say more about the environment and transcoding boundaries (I/O.) Console? Database? Servlet? JSP? Operating system?

Comment: Never heard of "french characters". I assume you mean accented characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Resource bundles in the ".properties" format, then this issue can be resolved by escaping al the not standard characters with their respective Unicode notation.

.propertie resource bundles are always in ISO-8859-1 encoding, so most likely you problem comes from converting the ISO-8859-1 encoding to UTF-8

You can easily convert all these characters to escaped Unicode representation by using one of these tools: native2ascii or AnyEdit

[using nonstandard characters in resource bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596276/use-cyrillic-properties-file-in-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the font, but the [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). I suggest you switch to [UTF-8](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), a good standard for international characters.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this has nothing to do with fonts, and the real problem is an encoding issue.

- Read The Absolute [Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- Make sure your code uses the correct encoding whenever it converts between bytes and strings. Avoid the methods/constructors/classes that use the platform default encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Character Encoding Filers at server side this will resolve your issue

please check bwloe link

[Character Encoding](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-235.html)