# UTF-8Characters not displayed correctly in

Tags: java, fonts, character-encoding, resourcebundle

we are working on a project for school, The project is mandatory tri-lingual (dutch, english and french) , so the answer "Change to English will not do".

All our classes and resource files are encoded in UTF-8 format, and alle non-standar english characters are diplayed correctly in the classes themself.

the problem is that once we try to display our text, alle non-standard english characters are distorted.

We hear alot that this is due to an encoding issue, but I sincerly doubt that, since our whole project is encode in UTF-8.

here is extract from the french resource bundle:

```
VIDEOSETTINGS = Réglages du Vidéo
SOUNDSETTINGS = Réglages du son
KEYBINDSETTINGS = Keybind Paramètres
LANGUAGESETTINGS = Paramètres de langue
DIFFICULTYSETTINGS = Paramètres de Difficulté
EXITSETTINGS = Sortie les paramètres
```

and this results in these following displayed strings.

[display result for provided resourcebundle extract](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/823/charactererror.png/)

I would be most gratefull for a solution for this problem

**EDIT**

for extra info we are building a desktop app using Swing.

Comment: pls give details about you aplication. It's a desktop app ? Swing?
`are diplayed correctly in the classes themself.` What on earth does that mean? Have you tried to print a non-ascii character in those buttons? What type of resources are those and how do you load them?

Comment: What is used for displaying that we see on the pic? Is it HTML? Is it a Swing application?

Comment: Another check to test that your resources are load correctly. Try getting the string from -say- SOUNDSETTINGS , and check that the length of the Java string is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show some code, where you read the resource files. But if you use PropertyResourceBundle with an InputStream in the constructor, the InputStream must be encoded in ISO-8859-1. In that case, characters that cannot be represented in ISO-8859-1 encoding must be represented by Unicode Escapes.

You can use `native2ascii` or `AnyEdit` as tools to convert Properties to unicode escapes, 
see [Use cyrillic .properties file in eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596276/use-cyrillic-properties-file-in-eclipse-project)

Comment: "**MUST** be encoding in ISO-8859-1" is awfully culturally imperialistic, now isn’t it? This seems like a clear design flaw. Forcing things into escaped numbers is a real mess and should never be required.

Comment: @tchrist: I would not call it imperialistic but it misses some foresight. Properties are part of Java since JDK 1.0 in 1996. In July 1996 Unicode 2.0 was released, in October 1996 UTF-8 was announced in RFC 2044. It is legacy like all the old 7bit internet-protocols

Comment: It is really sad that we are stuck with a year-1 design problem for another 15 years without any relief in sight. It’s completely fossilized.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to an encoding issue.

You are using the wrong decoder (probably ISO-8859-1) on UTF-8 encoded bytes.

Are these strings stored in a file? How are you loading the file? Via the `Properties` class? The `Properties` class always applies ISO-8859-1 decoding when loading the plain text format from an `InputStream`. If you are using `Properties`, use the `load(Reader)` overload, switch to the XML format, or re-write the file with the matching encoding. Also, if you are using `Resource.getBundle()` to load a properties file, you must use ISO-8859-1 encoding to write that file, escaping any non-Latin characters.

Since this is an encoding issue, it would be most helpful if you posted the code you have used to select the character encoding.

Comment: if i could i would also acept your answer as it also completely covers the question. I will read up on these issues, I (and apparently our teachers also) weren't aware that .proerties files are always in ISO-8859-1 encoding.

if it werent' so late in the project we would rebuild to use xml resourcebundles.

thanks for the help